# How to make slide show in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, three20, slideshow

I need to make slide show for number of images. But all the images are coming from server.
How to make this?

Is it possible to attach slide show feature in Three20 framework?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Three20 Framework is good for slideshow. Go with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three20 has slideshow functionality in the photo framework, but I've never used it. It's available in the [TTPhotoViewController](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTPhotoViewController.m#L420).